# Should I use new line or newline?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality

To demonstrate what pressing ENTER on the keyboard does, which sentence is correct?

1. The programmer can continue to write code on a new line.
2. The programmer can continue to write code on a newline.

Comment: A 'newline' is a character that ends an existing line. A new line is the line after that existing line.

Comment: @Mitch Thanks. -

Answer (score 3):

"new line" is the correct version.

---

You cannot write code on a newline because **newline** is a control character. You will not find "newline" as a word in most ordinary dictionaries because it is a technical term.

You can write code or any other text on a **new line**.

---

**Note**

The ASCII newline character is \n, also known as line feed.

‘\n’ = 10 = 0x0A = line feed

‘\r’ = 13 = 0x0D = carriage return

Comment: This is either specialist computer usage/terminology, or too basic for ELL.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - we can tell from the context that this is about computers. In any case, you won't find "newline" in an ordinary dictionary *except* when referring to computers.

Comment: So the question is 'Is _...write on a new line_ correct?'

Comment: But according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline newline can also be from pressing ENTER. https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b3/Illustration_of_a_newline.png/220px-Illustration_of_a_newline.png

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - I have edited my answer to reflect this.

Comment: @ention everyone - That makes no difference to my answer. *newline* and *Enter* are both escape sequences. You cannot write code on an escape sequence - it is just a sequence of a few bytes. A *new line* is a location where you can potentially write an unlimited amount of text.

Comment: I'm saying it's off topic on a site that aims at standard English for linguists.